# Response message: Non HTTP response message: no protocol: Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.MalformedURLException

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Try to execute a script using Jmeter 3.0.I am getting error for eg. If I applied load of 50 users, Ramp-up period 10, loop Count: 1

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-2

Sample Start: 1970-01-01 05:30:00 IST

Load time: 0

Connect Time: 0

Latency: 0

Size in bytes: 729

Headers size in bytes: 0

Body size in bytes: 729

Sample Count: 1

Error Count: 1

Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text

Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.MalformedURLException

Response message: Non HTTP response message: no protocol:


Response headers:


HTTPSampleResult fields:

ContentType:

DataEncoding: null
```

Can anyone help me why this type of error is showing?

Comment: Would you please share your `URL`? Your URL may not be properly formatted. Share your `HTTP Sampler`.

Comment: Yes off course. Here is the url https://libauth.np.edu.sg/TSP.

Comment: Thanks, please share your `HTTP Sampler` also.

Answer (score 4):

I tried few requests for the above URL in **JMeter 3.2**. It seems like there is no issue in the URL. Please make sure the configuration of HTTP sampler as shown below.

> **HTTP Sampler Configuration**

You can use **Redirect Automatically** option also.

[image: HTTP Sampler Configuration]

> **Output**

[image: HTTP Response]

Answer (score 0):

[Jmeter; how to solve the error 'Non HTTP response message: unknown protocol'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPum7.png)

1. If it is an https protocol include it in the text box and if not, you can leave it blank.
2. Type the url of the page in the text box labelled server name.
3. You can include the path if there is, in the path text box.

See image in the link below;

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPum7.png